# One to one mapping between two lists of strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have a pandas dataframe where 2 columns consist of lists of strings as shown below

```
df=pd.DataFrame( {'A' : [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'] ], 'B':[ ['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l'] ] })
```

I want to concatenate the first string element in the first list in A with the first string element in in the first list in B with a hyphen and so on. The final product would be another column C so that

```
df['C'] = [ ['a-g','b-h','c-i'], ['d-j','e-k','f-l' ] ]
```

I tried different functionalities with apply() and map() but nothing was producing the desired outcome, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with `apply` + `np.core.defchararray.add`:

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: add(add(x.A, '-'), x.B).tolist(), 1)
df

           A          B                C
0  [a, b, c]  [g, h, i]  [a-g, b-h, c-i]
1  [d, e, f]  [j, k, l]  [d-j, e-k, f-l]
```

Just remember what I said about storing data in lists.

---

If there is a possibility your columns are not equally sized, you can do an `if` check:

```
def foo(x):
    if len(x.A) == len(x.B):
        return add(add(x.A, '-'), x.B).tolist()
    return []

df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(foo, 1)
```

Comment: it is not working! Actually it is giving the same error as for the previous suggested answer 'Shape of passed values is (17, 2), indices imply (17, 34)' knowing that the shape of the dataframe is 17 rows and 34 columns. I tried your answer as it is, it works when the dataframe only consist of only these 2 columns, when you add extra columns of other types then it doesn't work anymore. I tried replacing df.apply by df[['A', 'B']].apply it now give me the following error 'could not broadcast input array from shape (15) into shape (2)'

Comment: @MartinHeusen If you're trying to concatenate all 34 columns, you better make sure each cell has the exact same number of elements.

Comment: no I'm not trying to concatenate the 34 columns, only 2 columns which I know that the length of lists in each row are the same. The length may differ from row to row, but in each row they are the same!

Comment: @MartinHeusen `df[['A', 'B']].apply` should work provided you've made sure to pass the `axis=1` argument at the end. Did you do that? It's important.

Comment: I did, here is my snippet of code I'm using and giving the error df_prim['Cur_pair'] = df_prim[['From', 'To']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.From).str.cat(pd.Series(x.To), sep='-').tolist(), 1)     I have a dataframe of currency exchange, where the 'From' and 'To' columns represent a currency pair the customer used

Comment: @MartinHeusen Ah, I changed to a new method, hopefully that works better.

Comment: From and To columns consist of lists of curremcy symbols. They are of the same size in each row

Comment: still giving the same error 'could not broadcast input array from shape (15) into shape (2)'. Even though I'm sure length of 'From' and 'To' lists in each row are the same, but can we add a condition to the apply that says if len(x.From)=len(x.To) else None?

Comment: @MartinHeusen Added an edit. Let me know if the method with defchararray.add worked or not.

Comment: no it didn't, perhaps I'm doing something stupid on my end but I actually found another way. I'm creating this currency pair thing first before using groupby() so now my list consist of currency pairs. Anyway thanks for all the help

Comment: @MartinHeusen That's unfortunate, but it's good to know you found a way. You may consider posting an answer, if you want to share with the community.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.cat`:

```
df['C'] = df.A.str.cat(df.B, sep='-')

df
#   A   B   C
#0  a   e   a-e
#1  b   f   b-f
#2  c   g   c-g
#3  d   h   d-h
```

Or directly add the two columns:

```
df.A + '-' + df.B

#0    a-e
#1    b-f
#2    c-g
#3    d-h
#dtype: object
```

---

*Update* on the edited data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']], 'B':[['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l']]})

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda r: [a+'-'+b for a,b in zip(r.A, r.B)], axis=1)

df
#           A           B                 C
#0  [a, b, c]   [g, h, i]   [a-g, b-h, c-i]
#1  [d, e, f]   [j, k, l]   [d-j, e-k, f-l]
```

Comment: @MartinHeusen can you edit your question to elaborate on that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I made a mistake in asking my question. The 2 columns I want to concatenate are each made of lists, so the dataframe is as follows df=pd.DataFrame( {'A' : [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'] ], 'B':[ ['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l'] ] }) and so my desired result is df['C'] = [ ['a-g','b-h','c-i'], ['d-j','e-k','f-l' ] ], can you help please?

Comment: Try `df['C'] = df.apply(lambda r: [a+'-'+b for a,b in zip(r.A, r.B)], axis=1)`.

Comment: tried your suggestion, it's giving the following error 'Shape of passed values is (17,2), indices imply (17,32)' the shape of the dataframe is (17,32)

Comment: any help @Psidom ?

Comment: @MartinHeusen you should edit your question with the expected input and output. Psidom answered to your original question..

Comment: I am not really sure where the error comes from, as it works for me for the example data you give. Maybe it's pandas version issue. Try to upgrade your `pandas` and see how it goes. `pip install pip --upgrade; pip install pandas --upgrade`.

Comment: upgraded to the newest version of pandas as suggested and still getting the same error message. Even if you think about it, what the snippet of code provided in the earlier comment by @Psidom do is that it takes the 2 lists in every row and put a '-' between them. What is desired is to take element by element in each list and do a one to one mapping between them so that the first string element in the first list in A is concatenated with the first string element in the first list in B and so on

Comment: Did you try my comment? `df['C'] = df.apply(lambda r: [a+'-'+b for a,b in zip(r.A, r.B)], axis=1)` Does it work on your example data?

Comment: yes I tried it @Psidom, and it is giving the same error I mentioned earlier. If it works at your end can you please share your finding in a comment with the outcome as you did in your first reply above.

Comment: Updated with the result of the method in the comment.

Comment: Hi @Psidom would you be able to help with the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020896/identify-for-each-timestamp-in-a-list-of-timestamps-if-they-are-in-a-weekday-we?noredirect=1#comment80996816_47020896

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Using `numpy.core.defchararray.add`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

a = np.array(df.values.tolist())

df.assign(C=add(add(a[:, 0], '-'), a[:, 1]).tolist())

           A          B                C
0  [a, b, c]  [g, h, i]  [a-g, b-h, c-i]
1  [d, e, f]  [j, k, l]  [d-j, e-k, f-l]
```

---

**Option 2**
Fun way with custom subclass of `list` and redefining `+`

```
class list_(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return list_(map('-'.join, (map(str, t) for t in zip(self, other))))

df.assign(C=df.applymap(list_).sum(1).apply(list))

           A          B                C
0  [a, b, c]  [g, h, i]  [a-g, b-h, c-i]
1  [d, e, f]  [j, k, l]  [d-j, e-k, f-l]
```