# Replace a list of timestamps in a pandas dataframe with a list of our for every timestamp in every row

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that consist of lists containing timestamps. I want to replace this list of timestamps with a list of the hour of each timestamp for every row. Below is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'id':[1,2], 'time':[ [2017-09-05 03:34:51,2016-03-07 05:24:55], [2016-02-06 03:14:21,2014-08-09 09:12:44, 2011-05-02 07:43:21] ] })
```

I would like a new column named 'hour' where

```
df['hour'] = [ [3,5], [3,9,7] ]
```

I tried different functionalities using map() and apply() but nothing produced the desired outcome, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` + `to_datetime`.

```
s = df.time.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce').hour.tolist() )
s

0       [3, 5]
1    [3, 9, 7]
Name: time, dtype: object

df['hour'] = s
df

   id                                               time       hour
0   1         [2017-09-05 03:34:51, 2016-03-07 05:24:55]     [3, 5]
1   2  [2016-02-06 03:14:21, 2014-08-09 09:12:44, 201...  [3, 9, 7]
```

Statutory warning, this is inefficient in general, because you have a column of lists.

---

If you want to know how I'd store this data, it'd be something like:

```
df

   id                 time
0   1  2017-09-05 03:34:51
1   1  2016-03-07 05:24:55
2   2  2016-02-06 03:14:21
3   2  2014-08-09 09:12:44
4   2  2011-05-02 07:43:21
```

Now, getting the hour is as easy as:

```
h = pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.hour
h

0    3
1    5
2    3
3    9
4    7
Name: time, dtype: int64

df['hour'] = h
```

If you want to perform group-wise computation, you can always use `df.groupby`.

Comment: Many thanks @COLDSPEED it worked perfectly. You are saying that a column of lists is inefficient, what is the best way to save so much information per user then? Say I'm collecting visiting times of different users to a website, some of them have 1000s of visits others only have 5 visits for example, If I save every visit timestamp in a new column I would have 1000s of columns just for timestmps and for some users those columns will be empty and that is very inefficient I think. depending on how mqny times this user visited the site. If you have a better idea please let me know. Thanks again

Comment: That is why I choose to save all timestamps per user in a list instead which could be of length 5 or 1000

Comment: @MartinHeusen See my edit, it's really simple. Also, a rule of thumb - how would you store this data in an SQL table? Certainly you cannot store lists and tuples there.

Comment: Thanks again. Funny enough my original data was in the format you mentioned (double index) but then I used groupby() to get all data per user in one row as I'm performing ML clustering which produce best results when data is grouped per user. Anyway it helped a lot. i hit the accept button too :)

Comment: one last thing, I posted another question today I and I'm having trouble getting a good answer for it. It is kinda similar to the one you answered. Can you please help me with it too, you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866480/one-to-one-mapping-between-two-lists-of-strings-in-a-pandas-dataframe/46866505?noredirect=1#comment80682631_46866505

Comment: @MartinHeusen I've answered, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869470/4909087